# How to fix IE 7 bug (Windows resize bug with GWT app)

Tags: css, gwt, internet-explorer-7, resize

Hi so when I resize the window smaller in IE7, go to the different section of the app than come back to the home and resize the window back to the full window the app does not resize itself to the full window. Is there a fix to this weird behavior?

Thanks.

```
<div id="contents">

<div id="top bar"></div> ----> resizing fine

<div id="center"> ----------->resizing fine
<div id="center1"></div> ------>* not resizing
<div id="center2"></div> ------>* not resizing
</div>

<div>
```

Weirdest thing is that it all resizes fine until you make it smaller, navigate away to different section come back than make it full screen above * is not resizing back to full screen..

Comment: I live example would help better to understand the problem

Comment: I dont have a live example, but in order to reproduce this bug, go to app home, make the window smaller, go to different section of the app (away from the home, window is still small at this point) come back to the home than make the home full screen. Home should resize itself to fit full screen but it doesn't browser is full screen but app is still small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was known bug for ie6, however... try setting

```
body {
   position: relative;
}
```

in your stylesheet

Comment: ..hhh.. it looks like not gwt, but ie layout handling bug. It would be much easier to answer if you provided your index.html and css contents.

Comment: I should have been more specific.. It is not actually the home page that is no resizing it a div within the home page.

Comment: There are numerous possible reasons, Mayumi; your markup & css would make answering easier.

Comment: And stylesheet, Mayumi (preferably full) :)

Comment: This could be another important information but center in above example is <g:LayoutPanel and divs not resizing are <g:Layer.

Comment: Sorry, Mayumi, this is not enough. My primary guess is that layout/styling is causing this behavior, however, I can't tell anything without looking at css (at least).